# Issue with Login form Layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I'm making a login form in Flutter, I'm using a `ListView` that has a `Container` as a child and it's child is a `Stack` widget which has `Positioned` children. Because of the Stack, I have to have a bound height, so hence the `Container` widget, which I gave the height: `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.2`. If I remove the `* 1.2` my `Button` and and `Text` widget don't show up, and when I click on the login with `* 1.2`, my validator pops up, red warning signs shows that your info is entered incorrectly, so I can't see the button anymore. Example in pictures:

This is with `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.2`

[image]

Then I try to login, validator pops, and now I can't see the button nor the text and link below the button:

[image]

The problem I am facing is, how do I layout this login form that can only be scrollable as far as it needs, so I don't have empty space after the Button, just to spread the form so it is visible, not get something like this if I increment the height of the `Container`?

[image]

Code:

```
ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.6,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assests/images/loginform.png',
                    scale: 2.5,
                    height: 60,
                    width: 119,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 25.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Form(
                          key: _registrationFormKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().name = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'Full name'),
                                validator: (thisValue) {
                                  if (thisValue.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter your full name';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().phoneNumber = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'Phone number'),
                                validator: _validateMobile,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().address = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'Address'),
                                validator: (thisValue) {
                                  if (thisValue.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter your address';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().companyName = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'Company name'),
                                validator: (thisValue) {
                                  if (thisValue.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter your company name';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    context.read<User>().website = value;
                                  },
                                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                      hintText: 'Website name'),
                                  validator: _validateWebsite),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().email = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'E-mail address'),
                                validator: _validateEmail,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 24.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                obscureText: _obscureText,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  context.read<User>().password = value;
                                },
                                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined),
                                    onPressed: _togglePassVisibility,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                validator: _validatePassword,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        FormField<bool>(
                          // 1
                          initialValue: _agree,
                          builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
                            // 2
                            return Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Checkbox(
                                      // 3
                                      value: state.value,
                                      onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() {
                                        // 4
                                        _agree = val;
                                        // 5
                                        state.didChange(val);
                                      }),
                                    ),
                                    const Text('I agree with'),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child: Text('Terms and conditions'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                // 6
                                state.errorText == null
                                    ? Text("")
                                    : Text(state.errorText,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                          // 7
                          validator: (val) => _validateTerms(_agree),
                        ),
                        AlarmButtons(
                          buttonColour: Color(0xFF29ABE2),
                          buttonText: 'CREATE ACCOUNT',
                          buttonTextColour: Colors.white,
                          buttonBorderSide: Colors.white,
                          onButtonPress: () async {
                            if (_registrationFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              signUpToCognito(context);
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                  context, ConfirmRegistrationScreen.id);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text('Already have an account?'),
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                              },
                              child: Text('Log in'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Check out `SliverFillRemaining`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple mistakes (or at least optimizations) in your code. I will go over them one by one:

1. If you have a small number of children that need to be scrolled, it is better to use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` instead of a list view. `ListView` builds its children lazily - that is, it only builds widgets that are visible on the screen. If you have only a handful of widgets with no complex animations, then you don't really need that. `SingleChildScrollView` is more flexible that a `ListView`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [...]
  )
)
```

2. It seems that you want the image to be on the background with the form validation on top of it. For that, you used a `Stack` and a `Column` as children to a `ListView`. Instead, have the `Stack` as a parent, with both the `ListView` and the image as children to the `Stack`. Now this might produce an error, as the `ListView` might expand infinitely. A simple solution is to wrap it within a `Positioned` widget with all its sides set to zero.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    BackgroundImageWidget(),
    Positioned(
      top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, // or width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight,
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for the help, I have removed the list view and added a SingleChildScrollView widget and a Columns as it's child. But that is not my question, as you can see in the question and pictures, the problem lays in the Container wrapped around the Stack, if I don't wrap the Stack, I get this error `'size.isFinite': is not true.`, so when I give it size(height) no error, just that one mistake where I can scroll more than I need to.

Comment: And I don't need a background image, I just positioned it above the `Form` and everything is fine, just the problem I described in the question above.

Comment: Your layout structuring makes your life harder, if you would go with a simpler approach the problem would probably disappear.
Try to avoid using `Stack` and `Positioned` where it is not really needed.
As far as I can see, this is quite simple layout and common form, so probably you can end up using `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column`where you would layout your elements.

Comment: @zpouip if I needed to place the elements exactly on position, following a designer UX design, would you still use SCSV and Column? OR use those 2 and something else (Align or similar widgets)? Thanks for the help

Comment: Probably those two and similar widgets.
I am not saying do not use `Stack` ever, it is just bit tricky with`Positioned` with not-so-standard device sizes e.g. iPhone SE, tablets and so on. 
If there is no better way only then I would use `Stack` and `Positioned`. 
Feel free to share more details on the requirements, maybe I can help.